# Comments_template doesn't work

Tags: loop, comments, disqus

If I use

```
comments_template();
```

it does not work at all.  But if I change it to

```
global $withcomments;
$withcomments = 1;
comments_template( 'comments.php', true );
```

it displays the comments template but I need to setup the Disqus plugin, and the plugin does not work.  I don't understand, getting comments to display is being incredibly difficult for some reason..

[dev link](https://ec2-54-88-47-53.compute-1.amazonaws.com/blog/)

---

*(tried to truncate non-pertinent code to keep it short)*

**index.php**

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content' );
    }
} ?>
```

---

**content.php**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $( ".content" ).hide ();
        $( ".entry-footer" ).hide ();

        $( ".more" ).click ( function () {
            $( this ).parent ().next ( '.content' ).show ( "blind", {direction : "vertical"}, 750 );
            $( this ).next ( '.entry-footer' ).show ( "fast" );
            $( this ).hide ();
        } );
        $( ".close" ).click ( function () {
            $( this ).parent ( ".content" ).hide ( "blind", {direction : "vertical"}, 750 );
            $( ".more" ).show ();
        } );
    } );
</script>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> itemscope itemprop="blogPost" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'header' ); ?>

    <div class="entry-content">

        <?php
        $entrycontent = $lithograph_theme_options['excerpt_content'];

        if ( $entrycontent != '' ) {
            switch ( $entrycontent ) {
                case 'excerpt':
                    if ( $lithograph_theme_options['slideout_content'] == 0 ) the_excerpt();
                    else : ?>
                        <span class="excerpt" itemprop="text">
                            <?php
                                if(!empty($post->post_excerpt)) the_excerpt();
                                else : echo get_first_paragraph(); ?>
                            <span class="more">+ more</span>
                        </span>
                        <span class="content" itemprop="text">
                            <?php echo get_the_post(); ?>
                            <span class="close">- close</span>
                            <?php 
                                get_template_part( 'content', 'footer' );
                                comments_template( 'comments.php', true );
                            ?>
                        </span>
                    <?php }
                    break;
                case 'content':
                    the_content();
                    global $withcomments;
                    $withcomments = 1;
                    comments_template( 'comments.php', true );
                    break;
            }
        } ?>

    </div>
</article>
```

---

*(generic comments template)*

**comments.php**

```
<?php if($comments) { ?>
    <ol>
        <?php foreach($comments as $comment) { ?>
            <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>">
                <?php if ($comment->comment_approved == '0') { ?>
                    <p>Your comment is awaiting approval</p>
                <?php }
                comment_text(); ?>
                <cite><?php comment_type(); ?> by <?php comment_author_link(); ?> on <?php comment_date(); ?> at <?php comment_time(); ?></cite>
            </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ol>
<?php } else { ?>
    <p>No comments yet</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Define "does not work at all". What exactly does or doesn't happen?

Comment: If I use comments_template(); the comments.php file does not appear to register at all, no comments are displayed, no comment textfield is displayed.  If I use the other, it works, but when I install and setup the Disqus plugin, the plugin has no effect.. doesn't seem to register at all, and the comments retain the exact same appearance as they did prior to installing the plugin.

Comment: did you get any solution for this, i am also having the same issue here.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you are trying to use the comments template out of context. The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_template) states:

> Loads the comment template. For use in single Post and Page displays. Will not work outside of single displays unless $withcomments is set to "1".

Unless you have a `is_single()` on the `index.php` or use the `$withcomments = 1` it's not intended to work. You should build out the `page.php` and `single.php` to load the comments into your template.

Comment: hey Greg, i have already set $withcomments to "1", it will show the default comment template, but am not getting the Disqus comment template.

Comment: Without seeing the site/code I cannot really help you. Have you tried following [these steps](https://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472005-wordpress-troubleshooting)?